# Pointer to a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, pointers, global

I have vast experience with `C`, but I'm fairly new using `JavaScript`. I've been searching for an explanation, but it seems like I'm not phrasing my question right. I need to tell a function which GLOBAL variable it should change. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function test(blah)
   {
    if (!window.blah)
     window.blah = 0;
    window.blah++;
    document.getElementById(blah).innerHTML = window.blah;
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="first">0</div>
  <input type="button" onclick="test('first')" value="change">
  <br>
  <div id="second">0</div>
  <input type="button" onclick="test('second')" value="change">
  <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

The purpose of the code is to have two separate counters - clicking the first button should increment `window.first` while clicking the second button should increment `window.second`. How do I phrase this?

Comment: Use window[blah] instead of window.blah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the variable name using the square bracket notation:

```
function test(blah)
{
    if (!window[blah])
        window[blah] = 0;
    window[blah]++;
    document.getElementById(blah).innerHTML = window[blah];
}
```

Hopefully this gives an idea of how the dot notation works in comparison to the square bracket notation;

```
var o = {
    key: 'value',
    foo: 'bar'
};

var key = 'foo';

console.log(o['foo']); // 'bar'
console.log(o[key]);   // 'bar'
console.log(o.key);    // 'value'
```

Comment: Oh, its like an array? Thank you!

Comment: @Ulrik No, it's like a map.

Comment: @Ulrik In JS, `something.blah` is the `blah` member of `something`, while `something[blah]` is the member which name is the string in `blah`.